# Question about riemann integration

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Let $Q \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ be a box and $f: Q \to \mathbb{R}$ be a integrable function with $f \geq 0$. Let $D$ be the set of discontinuities of $f$. Let $x \in Q \setminus D $, and choose a ball $B(x, \delta) \subseteq Q \setminus D $. Let $\tilde{Q}$ be small rectangle inside $B(x, \delta) $

Question : Why does it follow that

$$ \int\limits_Q f\geq \int\limits_{\tilde{Q}} f $$

?

---

**Edit:** Made $f \geq 0$ according to comments.

Comment: Is $f$ nonnegative?

Comment: yes, $f(x) > 0 $

Comment: Well then since $\tilde Q\subseteq Q$ the result is trivial.

Comment: yes, I know it is trivial but I cannot find it in my book such result... to prove this, do I have to use partitions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help to construct a general proof,

Assume for simplicity that $f:\mathbb R\rightarrow \mathbb R_+$ and that $f$ is continuous i.e we are just considering the one dimensional case. You can extend this to $\mathbb R^n$.

Let $[a,b]\subset\mathbb R$ for some $a,b\in\mathbb R$. Choose some arbitrary $x\in[a,b]$ and fix $\delta<min(|x-b|,|x-a|)$. Then $[x-\delta,x+\delta]\subset[a,b]$ Moreover we can write $[a,b]$ as,

$$[a,b]=[a,x-\delta)\bigcup [x-\delta,x+\delta]\bigcup (x+\delta,b]$$

This yields,

$$\int_{[a,b]}f=\int_{[a,x-\delta)\bigcup [x-\delta,x+\delta]\bigcup (x+\delta,b]}f=\int_{[a,x-\delta)}f+\int_{[x-\delta,x+\delta]}f+\int_{(x+\delta,b]}f$$
And since $f$ was positive it follows that,

$$\int_{[a,b]}f\geq\int_{[x-\delta,x+\delta]}f$$